# How do I earn credits?

Tags: forza-horizon-4

I want to earn more credits so I can purchase some of the more expensive player houses.

**Which sources of credit income are available to me?**

Other than races I'm unsure of the different ways to gain them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides races, there are a few ways to get credits.

- Finish certain Horizon Stories called "Businesses." These are **World's Fastest Rentals**, **Upgrade Heroes**, **The Car Files**, and I believe **Isha’s Taxis**. You have to be a particular level to open those but it's a good idea to get as many stars as possible in each, as you'll get cash every day.
- If you have the Fortune Island expansion, you can get 10 million credits by going through it and doing the treasure hunts.
- If you win Forza Edition cars from wheelspins or weekly challenges, you can sell them on the auction house for a good amount of money.
- Wheelspin-exclusive cars are also worth a lot of money. [Check if you have any of the cars on this list](https://forza.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Wheelspin_Reward_(FH4)) that you're willing to part with.
- You can also set up very long races using the route creator or just creating a circuit race with a large number of laps. The longer a race is, the more credits you get when you finish. I believe it's based on the length of the course so doing it over a very straight road might be the best way to go.
- Some cars have Car Mastery perks that give you credits, so check out the cars you have and see if you can buy any.

Comment: Great answer, I was completely unaware that I had the ability to sell off wheelspin cars! Abusing the custom race feature sounds interesting as well. Thanks!

Comment: Look out for custom races. When visiting a race marker you can select custom races and users have created easy races which earn you easy and fast credits.

Answer (score 0):

Flipping cars on the Auction House is by far the most lucrative legitimate way to earn credits in the game. I currently have every car in the game, unlocked all of the houses, and am at about 300 million credits.

Win a cheap car by entering a low bid just prior to the auction ending, or by outright buying out the auction if it is listed too low. Then list it for something that is in line with the current market.

Based on the rotating vehicles available during the seasonal events, the best vehicles to choose will change over time.